# Find Last 5 columns of a table

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to find the values of last 5 columns of a table?
Suppose if i have a table of 20 columns, i want to select all the values from the last 5 columns.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your use case, why you need such strange thing?

Comment: I'm taking data of 5 columns from a site where they update values every month. i want to store the last 3 updates. Suppose if i have jan, feb and march data, and during april update i want to delete jan data and db should have feb, mar and apr data. So i take the last 5 columns from db and check with data from site to make sure if there is any update. Make sense?

Comment: No that does not make sense. Your model is flawed. You shouldn't store each month's update in a column but in a *row*. Your table should have a column for the updated value and another column for the date/timestamp of the update and the one row for each update

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i name my column differently for each month. you may argue its not orthodox or against the law, but my requirement is this and i have no option.

Comment: Then you should ask whoever made that requirement why he/she needs this. What you are doing is called de-normalization and is almost always a very bad decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the answer

```
SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name='your_table'
order by ordinal_position
```

From ordinal_position we can get last 'n' columns we want.

Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 2):

Don't. It's stupid.

There shouldn't really *be* any order to the columns - they should just have names. It's just a convenience when testing or sitting at a DB console that `SELECT *` gives you them all.

There are *very* few cases where `SELECT *` makes sense in a live system. I can't think of any where you want whatever columns happen to be "last" on a table.

If you are really committed to doing this then you'll have to query the [information-schema](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/information-schema.html) or [system catalogues](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalogs.html). Get a list of the columns on a particular table and then build your SQL to query them.

However, if you aren't in control of this table then it's a meaningless task since you won't know what the information means. If you are in control of the table then you know what column-names there are and that's a better way to do it.

Comment: I'm taking data of 5 columns from a site where they update values every month. i want to store the last 3 updates. Suppose if i have jan, feb and march data, and during april update i want to delete jan data and db should have feb, mar and apr data. So i take the last 5 columns from db and check with data from site to make sure if there is any update. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Seems simple enough unless I misunderstood.

```
Select col16, col17, col18, col19, col20
From yourtable
```

Comment: My guess was that OP is looking for some kind of dynamic behavior - return last 5 column from any table. But anyway, your answer is correct :)

Comment: oops... the problem is even if the table is added with the 5 more columns, i want the last 5 columns. i dont want hardcode my column names.